# Adding margins to a scene that uses the Safe Area

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, interface-builder, safearealayoutguide

Is it possible to constrain to the Safe Area AND use margins?

I'm following Build a Basic UI [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/BuildABasicUI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH5-SW1). In the "Adopt Auto Layout" section, I'm supposed to add constraints to my stack view:

[image: Adding Constraints]

Even though I have "Constrain to margins" checked, here is what results:

[image]

No margins! The Stack View is now constrained to the Safe Area, which I don't think existed when that tutorial was written. Apparently the Safe Area doesn't allow you to constrain "Relative to margin" (that option is missing from the constraint dropdown):

[image]

I know I can turn Safe Area off (View > Utilities > Show File Inspector and deselect the checkbox for Use Safe Area Layout Guides) as this [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87708) recommends as the solution, resulting in the following:

[image: Margins enabled]

But I'd rather not lose the functionality of the Safe Area.

Is it not possible to use the Safe Area while taking advantage of layout margins? What is the recommended way to add margins into a scene that uses the Safe Area? There must be an elegant solution achievable through Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the default view margins by embedding your `UIStackView` inside a `UIView`:

[image]

Comment: Is this really the recommended solution? Is this documented anywhere? Seems like something people would want to do often, like with every new View Controller ever. Adding an extra view solely for this purpose seems kludgy, but maybe that's because I come from Android where adding extraneous views to the view hierarchy is discouraged.

Comment: Safe Area is new... the basic idea is: *Safe Area delimits the visible portion of the overall interface* ... and then margins of views can be used for appearance. It doesn't make as much sense when using a single view for the entire interface... but think about a "banner image" that would stretch the full width, and the content underneath would have margins. You may find this a good read (I found it searching, it's not my article): https://blog.smartnsoft.com/layout-guide-margins-insets-and-safe-area-demystified-on-ios-10-11-d6e7246d7cb8